# iOS app screen dimensions

Tags: ios, ipa

I have a problem when my apps ipa display in my device, because it does not display in fullscreen.

[image]

thanks

Comment: Is your app compatible with all the devices  i.e. iPads & iPhones. Note that if it is an iPhone app & you are opening in iPad, you would have this issue. As a beginner please explain your question as much as possible in order to avoid negative marking & better answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Change deployment target]

If your app is for iphone and try to run in ipad then black border issue arise. Otherwise layout seems off if it is for iphone and layout is not set for any particular device.

Comment: On which ios device are you running your app? And its deployment support it ?

Comment: You are not developing using  Xcode but adobe right ?
Than your question was not very clear, you need to post new question with complete details about your issue.

Comment: hello ... look at this article :: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2158880